# Finding proxy addresses in the Exchange Online GAL

Tags: office365, outlook-2016, exchange-server-2016

We have recently switched from Domino to O365 and Exchange Online. One of the issues we have discovered is that the email aliases (proxy addresses) of a mailbox do not seem to be searchable by endusers in the Global Address List via Outlook. For instance, we have a shared mailbox called accountspayable@domain.com, with an alias of a-p@domain.com. Both addresses receive mail fine, but if you search for a-p@domain.com when composing a new email, nothing is found, which is confusing to users. Is this the normal behavior? Is there a way to make the proxy addresses searchable in the GAL?

Answer (score 0):

The GAL is more or less used to translate displaynames to email addresses. It sound counter-intuitive to search on email addresses in the GAL when you could just as well enter that address yourself in the to field if you already know it.

Why not search for the displayname, which is probably much easier to remember?